# ASN1Parser.encodeVarBindList throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: asn.1

i'm using adventnet, and it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception while calling the methid ASN1Parser.encodeVarBindList(SnmpvarBind)

the SnmpvarBind varibale length is more than 1024

```
  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
            at com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.ASNTypes.encodeOctets(ASNTypes.java:255)
            at com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.SnmpString.encode(SnmpString.java:371)
            at com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.SnmpVarBind.encode(SnmpVarBind.java:206)
            at com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.ASN1Parser.encodeVarBindList(ASN1Parser.java:617)
            at com.adventnet.snmp.snmp2.ASN1ParserProxy.encodeVarBind(ASN1ParserProxy.java:64)
            at com.cisco.csrc.dcf.SnmpVarBindMgr.encodeVarBind(SnmpVarBindMgr.java:493)
```

Answer (score 0):

[WebNMS (Zoho, former Adventnet) forum](http://forums.webnms.com/topic/asn1parser-encodevarbindlist-throws-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception) is better place to ask these questions.

Even better is to ask the Zoho support directly.

BTW why they think that you had to decompile their classes?

Comment: i don't know how they say, the decompile their classes :) , it's totaly ridiculaous